# Related questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it just me that is tempted to add a Question like: *why isn't there one database to use instead of different database systems?* I mean, [this question](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/why-isnt-there-one-language-to-use-instead-of-different-programming-languages) got such a great, thought-provoking response!

Been quiet here on Meta. I think there should be badges for `Anthills Kicked` and `Wasp Nests Poked`. I would definitely work on those.

Comment: Yeah, I've been wrestling with the fact that the question seems off-topic to me. But others disagreed, and we absolutely needed the traffic.  The site has felt like it has been on life support for awhile now. That said, I still don't think it's a model question that we should follow!

Comment: Glad to hear that opinion @Ben. I think it's an awful question. And the long term direction will be the opposite of HNQ. Not that I think the SE dictate of "discussions taboo" is reasonable. Just **this** discussion. TBH the latex-OS one is more CS AND more edu than this one

Comment: A good site very few people use vs a less good site that exposes a lot of content to many... Well, we know the results of these two directions. Who was that old guy who developed knowledge in people by asking questions? I forget, it was so long ago.

Comment: Are you equating Socrates with the bedlam in "progress" out here?!?!

Comment: @Rusi I was simply saying that you get farther asking questions than telling people stuff. And that idea has been around a while. Discussion produces more than dictation.

Comment: Sure but all qs are not equal surely??  The question is one of great interest to me (I think the first comment is mine). But this particular formulation I don't like. I find it ill-posed, poorly formated unresearched and a rant. Evidently a number of ppl feel the same if the comments are believed. So frankly I'm conflicted : to give my take on it or not.

Comment: I must admit though that some of the responses have been educative for me eg the one on Java-MS history. And also the one drawing link between politics and language proliferation has expanded my horizon. So there's that also...